# Telerik RadEditor image manager issues

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radeditor

We are using Telerik RadEditor control in our project and having some problems with its integration with our user documents storage engine. We've implemented custom content provider for Telerik image manager and it shows correct documents in dialog. But in doesn't switch between images while selection. You can see this on [this picture](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/K5gFx7XvDkaFG95g5peUkQ?feat=directlink). We've tested this behaviour on the blank ASP.NET page without any additional CSS or JS. Rad editor tag could be found below. Please help! Why do this could happen?

```
<telerik:RadEditor ID="radEditor" runat="server" 
    ToolbarMode="ShowOnFocus"
    ToolsWidth="402"
    EditModes="Design"
    ToolsFile="~/RadEditor.xml"
    Skin="Default">
    <ImageManager ViewPaths="IMAGES" EnableImageEditor="False" ContentProviderTypeName="FileStorageContentProvider, App_CODE" />
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work as intended without your ContentProvider?  I'm wondering if the logic in your contentprovider is causing the issue.  I don't see anything out of the oridinary from your control properties.

Comment: Yes, it maybe true, because it works without content provider. But what things in content provider could lead to these effects. I've checked requests in Firebug and saw that files descriptions and links were came correctly to the browser. And dialog shows them correct. It just dosen't switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to FiveTools! The issue was in content provider. Full path to item (including item name) should be passed to the 'location' parameter of the FileItem constructor. Otherwise selection would be broken.

Comment: the documentation states for the FileItem that Location can be set to string.empty, and the system will automatically build the location string for you, but I am seeing some strangeness with this on the 4.0 build of the Telerik.Web.UI dlls

Comment: I just added the Location assignment from my content provider, and the image thumbnails are showing up, but when I click insert, the image is not added. what could I be doing wrong? there is no exception, and there are not any exceptions in the javascript either.